# Javascript:console shows the error: redeclaration of import SNAKE_SPEED

Tags: javascript, import

```
import {SNAKE_SPEED, draw as drawSnake} from './snake.js'

let lastRenderTime = 0;

function main (currentTime) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    const secondsSinceLastRender = (currentTime - lastRenderTime) / 1000
    if (secondsSinceLastRender < 1/SNAKE_SPEED) return
    console.log('Render');
    lastRenderTime = currentTime;
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(main);

function draw () {
    drawSnake()
}
```

I make the declaration that import SNAKE_SPEED only once but it says there is redeclaration.
I don't know how to fix.

Error message:
[Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of import SNAKE_SPEED game.js:4:6note: Previously declared at line 1, column 8game.js:1:8
GEThttp://localhost/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcovr.png)

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire error message into your question?

Comment: I have added the entire error message, check it.